# Como remover parte decimal nula (00) da formatação de número em JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, string, formatação

Pretendo em JavaScript ter o seguinte resultado:

| Entrada | Saída esperada |
| --- | --- |
| 1.6 | 1,60€ |
| 1 | 1€ |
| 1.55 | 1,55€ |

Já tentei:

```
num.toLocaleString('pt-PT', {
  minimumFractionDigits: 0,
  maximumFractionDigits: 2
}) + '€';
```

Mas sem sucesso, uma vez que, para entrada `1.6`, recebo `1,6€`, sendo que desejo dois dígitos decimais nesse tipo de cenário.

Comment: se não vai mudar o formato (pelo menos é o que aparece na tabela), não seria mais simples só concatenar o "€"?  se tem "1.55" e quer retornar o mesmo formato não percebo pq utilizar o `toLocaleString`

Comment: @RicardoPontual, o `toLocaleString` é provavelmente para formatar o número corretamente de acordo com o padrão `pt-PT`. Veja que `12345.67` é diferente de `12 345,67` (resultado da formatação).

Comment: sim, mas pelo que tem exemplos não é necessário, dai a minha dúvida :)

Comment: @RicardoPontual, foi erro meu na edição, só vi agora, obrigado! :) Na verdade os [exemplos originais](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/revisions/f8e5becc-2a93-4fd2-8be8-fb188e441153/view-source) mostravam isso sim.

Comment: Preciso formatar, para a moeda pt_PT, se o separador decimal for ponto tem de ficar virgula

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A resposta mais simples é remover o `,00` manualmente no caso deste existir, uma vez que não existe opção de formatação que cobre esse formato.

```js
function fmt(num) {
  return num
    .toLocaleString('pt-PT', {
      minimumFractionDigits: 2,
      maximumFractionDigits: 2
    })
    .replace(/,00$/, '') + '€';
}

console.log(fmt(1));
console.log(fmt(1.2));
console.log(fmt(1.23));
```

Observe que, se a formatação for muito frequente, talvez valha a pena utilizar uma instância "especializada" da API [`Intl.NumberFormat`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Intl/NumberFormat).

Comment: Vou dar uma vista de olhos Intl.NumberFormat, mas a sua solução resolveu o problema para já, obrigado

Comment: Dá para evitar o uso do replace, ` return num.toLocaleString('pt-PT', {minimumFractionDigits: "0",      style:"currency", currency: "EUR", currencyDisplay: "symbol"});`

Comment: @AugustoVasques, tinha pensado nisso, mas nesse caso, `1.1` não ficaria `1,10€`, mas sim `1,1 €`. Até onde vejo, realmente parece um formato extremamente customizado que foge dos padrões mesmo...